# Import MySQL Backup Table-Names lowercase

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to create Tables automatically through JAVA in a clean Database evironment by using executing ./bin/mysql ... < Tables.sql which works fine, except for the tables being created all lowercase despite their names being written normally in the .sql file. Any ideas on how to solve that? Adding lower_case_table_names = 2 to the ini did not help. I'm on windows btw.

Comment: Uhm, what does this have to do with Java?

Comment: Any particular reason that the table names being in lower case worries you? In my experience ( limited in the case of mysql I have to admit ), SQL is generally not case sensitive

Comment: Are you sure you have edited the write MySQL config file? I have seen this happen a bunch of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with replacing the `YOUR_DATABASE_NAME` with your DB name

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',db,'.',tb,' RENAME ',db,'.',LOWER(tb),';')
FROM
    (SELECT table_schema db,table_name tb
     FROM information_schema.tables WHERE
     table_schema in (YOUR_DATABASE_NAME)
    ) A;
```